# Recharts Line Chart displays strange by showing data for 1 hour interval in Xasis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to make it similar to this chart but it shows strange.

[I need a result like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yteV7.png)

[Here's the demo project running on Stackbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-saydmr?file=src/App.js)

The x-axis shows from 9 am-3 pm (1-hour interval) and the time-value data interval is 1 minute but after doing this the line is strange (maybe too narrow).
Do you have any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-basic-line-chart-forked-uq9w3x?file=/index.js Does this help?

Comment: @DreamBold If you add more data as me, it will show the same result. 
The line is too narrow doesn't same as the result imagei want. 
The data is 1 minute interval from 9am to 3pm (9:01, 9:02....14:59) and axis show 9am-3pm with 1 hour interval (9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
https://mt.vcsc.com.vn/board

Comment: THen you should expand the axis or increase the time interval

Answer (score -1):

there are too many data changes, it looks good only if you make the graph width at least 900px.

you can try to change the data once in 10 seconds then the graph look ok also with 250 px width

```js
let j = 0
  let value = parseFloat(getRandomNumber(980, 1050).toFixed(2))
  for (let i = 0; i < totalRange / (60 * 1000) - 1; i++) {

    if (j % 10 === 0) {
      value = parseFloat(getRandomNumber(980, 1050).toFixed(2))
    }
    const next = start.add(1, 'minutes').valueOf();

    arr.push({
      time: next,
      value,
    });
    j++
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks better. But this is just fake data, I will test again when do it with real data